# Mysql_num_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Tags: php, sql

i haved tried to check the exist row in sql database but it always return this error. I tried research they gave some solutions but not work. Please help!!

```
$usersexist = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT phone FROM usersacc WHERE phone = '$pho'");

        $count= mysql_num_rows($usersexist) or die(mysql_error());
        if($count > 0)
        {
         $result_data = array( 
           'ResultArray' => 'Exist',
            ); 
        }
        else
        {
        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO usersacc
(phone, password) VALUES('$pho', '$pass')");


        #Build the result array (Assign keys to the values) 
        $result_data = array( 
           'ResultArray' => 'success',
            ); 
        }
        #Output the JSON data 
        echo json_encode($result_data);
```

Answer (score 4):

You are mixin mysqi with mysql. Try with this -

```
$usersexist = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT phone FROM usersacc WHERE phone = '$pho'") or die(mysqli_error());

$count= mysqli_num_rows($usersexist);

if($count > 0) {
//rest of your code
```

Comment: tks a lot, i got that

Comment: Happy to help you..And plz accept the answer if it solves the problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

Mysql is not mysqli. You should work with $userexist->num_rows (object context) or mysqli_num_rows($userexist) procedual context here. Also you should check if $userexist didnt just return false (failed query). So like this:

```
$usersexist = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT phone FROM usersacc WHERE phone = '$pho'");

if(!$userexist)
    die("query failed");


$count = mysqli_num_rows($userexist);
if($count > 0)
{
 $result_data = array( 
   'ResultArray' => 'Exist',
    ); 
}
else
{
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO usersacc
(phone, password) VALUES('$pho', '$pass')");


#Build the result array (Assign keys to the values) 
$result_data = array( 
   'ResultArray' => 'success',
    ); 
}
#Output the JSON data 
echo json_encode($result_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't use mysql if you used mysqli.

```
mysql_num_rows($usersexist)
```

correct

```
mysqli_num_rows($usersexist)
```